# RoR pagination, adding image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using will_paginate for pagination.

in this iam using images for clicking next and previous.

like, :prev_label & :next_label  and it is working good

but, i want to add images to page numbers as well, and on clicking next it should roll over to next image.

Please give me solution for this

Comment: Have you read [this blog post](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate), in particular the *Doing it your way* section?

Answer (score 0):

This example helps you

In Model

```
   @table_name = ModelName.paginate(:all, :page => params[:page], :per_page =>number_of_record)
```

In view use

```
<%= will_paginate  @table_name, :inner_window =>1, :outer_window   => -2 %>
```

and for image use paperclip plugin

Answer (score 0):

For creating a custom paginator you need to subclass the WillPaginate::LinkRenderer class, and pass it as a parameter in your view, as

```
<%= will_paginate(@users, :renderer => MyCustomLinkRenderer) %>
```

Check [this tutorial](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate), or see the [actual class](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/df42582bde7c6c8ea2fd08ed532876909fb06500/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb) definition to see how it gets rendered